# How to change a global variable in a bash script from outside so the change is reflected in a while loop?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I have a bash script in Ubuntu that activates a function (that i also wrote) that's located in the same script and sets it to run in the background, in the following way:

```
my script:
.
.
my_func &
do some stuff (that i don't know how much time it's gonna take)
global_var=1
```

my_func is a function that has a while loop and it's condition is to run while

```
global_var -ne 1
```

But it doesn't work. After the value is changed to 1 iutside the loop the change doesn't seem to propagate to the function since the while loop keeps running.

my_func collects statistics about my script performance so it has to finsih gracefully and i can't just force-kill it after the program is done. That's why i have to be able to tell it to stop.

Need help telling it to stop.

Comment: Background process doesn't run in the same shell and shares no memory with the parent shell.

Comment: Every subshell has it's own copy of the environment, you would be better off creating a lock file or similar and checking it's existence, which will be independent of the shell environment.

Answer (score 0):

when you run this function in the background it does not share access or memory with the script that run it. you will need to employ some other method.

the most elegant way would be to see if you cant get the function to understand by itself that it needs to stop. however, if that is not possible in your situation one of the oldest and easiest methods is to have a shared data file, filled with whatever variables you need to be common amongst your scripts.

so instead of global var, you write to vars.txt, stopfunction=1
and in your background script its constantly checking this file (or database) each loop to see what the variable is.

alternatively if your program allows this format you may be able to export data. put your function into another shell script and run it from the first in background.

```
#!/bin/sh

globalvar="something"
export globalvar
./2.sh &

echo "finished"
```

and then in 2.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

sleep 5
echo "this is global: $globalvar"
```

for example, i dont know if this will work for your case, but ive used similar tricks for scripts like what it sounds like you are trying to do.

though this method would require that changing global var and calling the script happen is some sort of larger loop, even if they are asynchronous.